# checkbox'ed list on each tab

Tags: android, listview, android-layout

I am new to this community as well as to android development. 
For my study I need to make a (yes/no)questionnaire divided into 3 groups, some of the questions are quite long, so I want to make a part of it as big text and other part below as a small one.

I from tutorial on dev.and.com and made a TabLayout and for the moment I also have a LinearLayout for my questions

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >

    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="2dp">

    <TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/text_large"
    android:textSize="16sp">
    </TextView>
    <TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/text_small"
    android:textSize="12sp">
    </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:gravity="right">
    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/checkBxc">

    </CheckBox>
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Same is going to be for all of groups.

Code for tabLayout is like [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html)

And AgroupActivity just displays a line of text right now (for testing purposes).

How can I make my layout to look like a list in each tab I have? Or maybe there are some other possibilities? As I understood, a simple ListView can't have anything(checkboxes in my case) in its tag?

Answer (score 0):

You could use ListView to display a layout look like a list  in each tabs.
With each tab content you use a ListView for each tab:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ListView android:id="@+id/android:list"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And custom row (your_custom_row.xml) for each rows in ListView:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      >
      <TableRow
         android:gravity="left"
         >
         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/row_textview1"
             android:textSize="25sp"
             android:textStyle="bold"
             android:layout_width="200dp"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:lines="1"/>
         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/row_textview2"
             android:textSize="16sp"     
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:gravity="right"
             android:paddingRight="10dp"
             android:lines="1"/>
      </TableRow>
   </TableLayout>
```

and use Adapter to bind data to your ListView.

Comment: but the problem is that I need a checkbox next to question, but listview can store only a line of text, isn't so?

Comment: You can store TextView, ImageView, Checkbox... in ListView. I gave you an example of custom row (which use TableLayout for displaying a row)

Comment: Set your list_row to have a horizontal layout and you can have items next to each other.